# How to upsert a GORM model with its association?

Tags: go, go-gorm

I have the structs defined as follows

```
type Book struct {
  ID    uint      `gorm:"primaryKey;auto_increment;not_null;type:bigint"`
  Name  string
  ISBN  string    `gorm:"uniqueIndex:unique_isbn"`
  Price PriceDetail
}

type PriceDetail struct {
  ID      uint      `gorm:"primaryKey;auto_increment;not_null;type:bigint"`
  Price   flaot64
  BookID  uint      `gorm:"uniqueIndex:unique_book_id"`
}
```

The two unique statements are important here as I want to maintain that "each book has a unique ISBN" and Book-PriceDetail is a strict "has one" relation.

here is what I am trying for Upsert

```
db.Session(&gorm.Session{FullSaveAssociations: true}).
Clauses(clause.OnConflict{
  Columns:   []clause.Column{{Name: "isbn"}}, // key colume
  DoUpdates: clause.AssignmentColumns([]string{"name"}), // column needed to be updated
}).Save(&book)
```

I am getting unique key violation for the above and not able to find a way around it.

My requirement is - Create a book record with associated price detail record if the record doesn't already exist. If it exists, update the changes.

Edit : I was able to achieve this by the below approach. Is there any better way to do it? I am firing an extra query to look for the record here.

```
    var bks Book
    bks.ISBN = book.ISBN

    db.Session(&gorm.Session{FUllSaveAssociations: true}).
       Clauses(clause.OnConflict{
          Columns: []clause.Column{{Name: "isbn"}}
          DoUpdates: clause.AssignmentColumns([]string{"name"})
       })

    if err := db.Preload("Price").First(&bks).Error; errors.Is(err, gorm.ErrRecordNotFound) {
         db.Create(&book)
    } else {
         book.Price.ID = bks.Price.ID
         db.Save(&book)
    }
```

Comment: Did you try using the `foreignKey` tag in your `Book` struct? The struct tag should look something like this for the `Book` struct: `gorm:"foreignKey:BookID"`

Comment: @MohitDodhia I have not used `gorm:"foreignKey:BookID"` in the `Book` struct but that foreign key constraint is implied in the declaration and is interpreted correctly by gorm. I used [this](https://gorm.io/docs/has_one.html#Declare) as reference for declaring the model.